# Communication between react apps

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass PROPS from one react app to another react app.

I know about sharing props between the components and usage of redux and flux.

Is there any way or any external library which does this functionality?

Comment: Can you describe your use case? How are the 2 apps structured? running?

Comment: Firstly, I just want to know, is this technically possible? If so, the first app will basically try to pass an ID which needs to be accessed by the second app to load the details based on the ID.

Comment: Is there a server? Why dont you want to go through it ? Please describe more

Comment: I hope you know about intents in react-native. My aim is to achieve that in react. Yes, there is a server.

Comment: ah ok. You can do that as part of your react-router params, if you are using react-router.

Comment: Ok basically you mean through the Links and pass as query params right?

Comment: How can I use routing if its not a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

In React App 1

```
  <button onClick={() => window.replace('http://app2.com/showDetails/zce1ifkfhy')}> Show Details </button>
```

In React App 2

```
  <Router>
     ....
      <Route
        path="/showDetails/:id"
        component={ShowDetailsComponent}
      />
  </Router>
```

ShowDetailsComponent

```
const ShowDetailsComponent = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Id from app1: {match.params.id}</h3>
  </div>
);
```